# How to move mailboxes from one database to another via cmdlet

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I have 10 Exchange mailboxdatabases, one of them is having log issues where DPM or WSB are not removing the logs after backups so I need to move all the mailboxes off this Database.  How do I select all the mailboxes in this database and move them to the new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure you want to move all mailboxes, then you can just do the following:

```
Get-Mailbox –Database "SOURCE_DATABASE" | New-MoveRequest –TargetDatabase "TARGET_DATABASE"
```

That would force all mailboxes that are in that source database to start a MoveRequest to the new database.  You could then use the EMC to look at the move requests and see how the individual moves are progressing.

Comment: Excellent thank you, I was thinking of writing a more convoluted PS script.